# OpenCL kernel definition syntax

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I'm trying to clarify some structs and syntax in OpenCL. Currently I'm working with VS2013 and OpenCL Emulator-Debugger. I started working with the demo project which comes with the emulator and stuck into this:

```
__Kernel(hello)
 __ArgNULL
  { 
   ...
  }
```

Just two lines above there is this:

```
//__kernel void
//hello()
```

What's the difference between them? As far as I understand from the documentation (here: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/OpenCL-Emu-Documentation-2.pdf

and here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.x-latest.pdf) the first one is just a Macro definition in the OCL-Emu environment for the second one, but there isn't a clear and definite answer. Is this right?

Comment: Kernel is just a normal C function (conforming to a number of restrictions) with an attribute `__kernel`.

Comment: @SK-logic Yes I know this. I can't make clear which is the proper syntax to define one and what's the difference between the above syntaxes I've mentioned.

Comment: There is only one syntax - `__kernel` attribute. Your code above is apparently some weird macro, expand macros first to see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is right, the first one is a macro.

`__Kernel()` is a macro, and `__kernel` is a special CL flag to declare a C99 function as a GPU code entry function (kernel function).

So this `__Kernel(hello)` expands to `__kernel hello`
And `__ArgNULL` expands to `()`.
Giving you normal CL code: `__kernel hello() { ... }`

In this Emu-CL case, the macros are probably needed, since it doesn't internally expand to CL code. The macros are a way to simplify and adapt the language to a CL-like expressions.